# Does having a recursive template parameter pack function create a specific function for each iteration?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, compiler-optimization, variadic-functions

Let's say I re-create `printf` using a parameter pack:

```
void printf(const char* string)
{
    std::cout << string;
}

template <typename T, typename... Params>
void printf(const char* string, T first, Params... p)
{
    while (*string != '\0')
    {
        if (*string == '%' && *(string + 1) != '%')
        {
                std::cout << first;
                string += 2;
                printf(string, p...);
                return;
        }

        std::cout << *string++;
    }
}
```

I call the function with the following parameters:

```
printf("%d is the answer to life, the universe, and everything. Pi = %f", 42, 3.14);
```

Would the compiler create 2 different functions with different signatures?

`printf(const char*, int, Params...);`
and `printf(const char*, double, Params...);`

If so, a function call with 10 arguments would result in 10 different functions being created. Does the compiler optimize this at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect that the following two template instances to result from this call:

```
printf(const char*, int, double);
```

and

```
printf(const char*, double);
```

And, yes, if you pass eleven parameters to this `printf()`, the compiler will generate ten instances of the template function. This is why templates have a reputation, deservingly so, for creating code bloat.

If you have, say

```
printf("Foo %d\n", 10);

printf("Bar %d\n", 20);
```

I would expect that both template instances will be identical, and merged together at link time. But that's a small consolation.

Comment: Just a comment for OP: why is this surprising? For a regualr (non parameter pack) template with one type (C<T>); if it is used with ten different concrete types it will result in ten different template instances.